# Creating unique primary key to ignore duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have a main large table which I have had to put into 3rd normal form and into smaller tables (with primary and foreign keys linking them). The table is about renting books.

I have a customer table which I need to create a primary key for. In the main large table there are duplicates of the customer_id, as the table as a whole is for renting the books, so one customer may have more than one renting.

The table I am currently trying to add a primary key for will not have any nulls or duplicates, however i am unsure how to create the primary key for this without the error- unsure how to make it unique.

```
CREATE TABLE customer AS 
    SELECT cust_id, country_id, name, address, postcode
    FROM BOOKS
    WHERE cust_id != 0;


ALTER TABLE customer
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (cust_id);
```

Is anyone able to help me in how to create the primary key on my customer table, but just taking each unique cust_id from the main table.

Comment: Add DISTINCT to the SELECT so you only get one row and not duplicates. A "Customer" table shouldn't have the same customer represented multiple times.

Comment: @pmbAustin I have a specialisation from my customer of 2 types of customers, and they inherit the primary key of cust_id, I've tried using the same alter table add primary key command above but it comes up with an error. Also one is currently named cust_id and one customer_id, do i rename these to be the same? and do you know how i would go about this?

Comment: in which table where customer_id column from?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server the straightforward way to add unique keys is to use `IDENTITY`.  Identity fields are integer fields that auto populate successive values by a specified start value and interval.  If you don't specify the interval it will start at 1 and increase the value by 1 each time a value is assigned.

While it's usually done when creating a table, you can do it in your `ALTER TABLE` step, and it will assign values when added to an existing table.  I've explicitly specified the start value and interval that matches the default to show the syntax :

```
ALTER TABLE customer
    ADD cust_id int not null PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
```